# iPhone Visual VoiceMail in Israel

Tags: iphone, voicemail, visual-voicemail

I brought my unlocked iPhone 4S to Israel and got a local SIM card. The voicemail button is calling the voicemail instead of showing me the visual voicemail.

I asked my provider about it (Cellcom) and they had no idea what I was talking about. They didn't even know Visual Voicemail existed.

Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: As far as i know, Israeli providers such as Cellcom does not support Visual Voicemail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

Visual Voicemail needs to be activated by the service provider as it uses their services. It requires some work on their side, so I would imagine they need a big group of people wanting it.

Out of interest, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_voicemail) Wikipedia article briefly covers the topic. There is no open standard for this feature, so it hasn't been deployed on a lot of networks due to the service provider having to provide the required interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you go to [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1937) page on the Apple website you will find a list of carriers that support Visual Voicemail.

Not all carriers have Visual Voicemail. Although it is shown as a main feature of iPhone